# Problem when trying to define Show for my Point3D type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to define Show for my `Point3D` type:

```
type Point3D = (Integer, Integer, Integer)

instance Show Point3D where
    show (x,y,z) = "<" ++ (show x) ++ "," ++ (show y) ++ "," ++ (show z) ++ ">"
```

yet I must be missing something in the sintax, as I am always getting an error:

> ```
> Illegal instance declaration for `Show Point3D'
>
>     (All instance types must be of the form (T t1 ... tn)
>      where T is not a synonym.
>      Use -XTypeSynonymInstances if you want to disable this.)
> In the instance declaration for `Show Point3D'
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See also [newtype](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Newtype).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As alternative to the other proposals you can define Point3D as a record:

```
data Point3D = Point3D { x :: Int, y :: Int, z :: Int }

instance Show Point3D where
    show (Point3D x y z) = concat ["<", show x, ",", show y, ",", show z, ">"]
```

Or you put the tripel inside a new type:

```
data Point3D = Point3D (Int, Int, Int)

instance Show Point3D where
    show (Point3D (x,y,z)) = concat ["<",(show x),",",show y,",",show z,">"]
```

See http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses for the pros and cons of these versions.

**[Edit]**

I learned that it's better to write the last version as

```
newtype Point3D = Point3D (Int, Int, Int)

instance Show Point3D where
    show (Point3D (x,y,z)) = concat ["<",(show x),",",show y,",",show z,">"]
```

The `newtype` keyword was made for exactly this kind of situation. The advantage over `data` is that the compiler doesn't need to "wrap" the underlying type but can keep it as internal representation, which is both faster and "lazier".

Comment: These two type definition are virtually the same, they only differ in the syntax you can use to pattern match and construct value. And the first variant defines additional selector functions. But there semantics is almost the same. The only real difference between them is the fact that the first variant defines a curried constructor, while the second variant defines a tupled constructor. Which means they can represent different levels of undefined-ness.

Comment: Of course they are quite similar. The first version gives you extractor and copy methods for free, while the second is good when you need to interface with code that uses tuples.

Answer (score 8):

```
type Point3D = (Integer, Integer, Integer)
```

This code defines a name: `Point3D` , which is just an abbreviation of `(Integer,Integer,Integer)`. In every context these two type expressions are equivalent. And for the latter, there is already a show instance in the `Prelude` defined.

If you really need a different string representation of 3d point you have the following alternatives:

- Define a simple function `formatPoint :: Point3D -> String`
- Change your type to be different from a standard 3-tuple of integers, e.g. `newtype Point3D = P (Integer,Integer,Integer)`
- Enable the language extensions mentioned in the error message.

I would defer enabling language extensions until you have mastered the core of Haskell, since they have the potential of being dangerous and or confusing.

The newtype solution changes only the syntax of values not their memory representation at runtime.

Comment: I forgot to explain the actual error message, because I jumped directly to what -- I believed -- was the underlying problem. So here comes the explanation: Haskell forbids to define type class instances for type aliases, i.e. names defined by a line `type Bla = ...`. This is done, because it may lead to confusion, when you try to give two instances for the same type by using two different names for that type. This what you tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

Haskell separates the namespace of values and functions from the namespace of types, type classes, and modules by the case of the first letter of names. I.e. functions always have to start with a lowercase letter. While names of types have to start with an uppercase letter. Therefore the type class `Show` requires a function `show`.

Try it with:

```
type Point3D = (Integer, Integer, Integer)

instance Show Point3D where
    show (x,y,z) = show ""
```

Comment: I am with your code getting the following error:    Pattern bindings (except simple variables) not allowed in instance declarations
      Show (x, y, z) = Show ""